# linq minus of to sum values

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I want below SQL Query to be written in entity framework or LINQ.Can any one please help me on this

SQL Query:

```
select sum(CreditAmount)-sum(DebitAmount) 
from [dbo].[JournalEntries] 
where FKSubscriberID =3 and FKAccountID =1
```

Comment: Have you tried *anything* yet? This looks like it should be reasonably simple, particularly if you consider it to be a `sum(CreditAmount-DebitAmount)`. Please show what you've tried, and what went wrong. I suggest you edit your title to be clearer, too.

Comment: yea I agree at least for sum(CreditAmount-DebitAmount) this also I need LINQ or EF query

Comment: Right - so how far have you got? Do you already have the EF code set up? Are you able to do the filtering? What part is causing you a problem?

Comment: @JonSkeet : Just i need the Linq or EF query.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You need to show effort, show what you've tried and what went wrong, so we can help you help yourself. Hint: The `Sum` method is going to be useful to you.

Comment: @JonSkeet
I tried below code but its wrong. I struck here 
  var query = from stk in dbContext.JournalEntries
                        group stk by stk.FKSubscriberID into stkg
                        where stkg.Key == subscriberPaymentProfileDTO.FKSubscriberID 
                        select new
                        {

                            Available = stkg.Sum(s => s.CreditAmount) - stkg.Sum(s => s.DebitAmount)
                        };

Comment: Please put that code *in the question* and give more details as to what happened, rather than just "I stuck here". Also I strongly suggest you take my hint about summing the difference between credit and debit rather than summit credit and separately summing debit.

Answer (score 0):

In general, assuming C#, convert SQL to LINQ by converting phrases in LINQ comprehension syntax order, and if SQL has table aliases, use them in LINQ as range variables. Functions such as `DISTINCT` or `TOP` are called as functions over the whole query at the end. Doing multiple `SUM` in one query without the optimization @JonSkeet suggests requires an empty `group`...`by` to create an aggregate and then `First()` to reduce to a value:

```
(from je in dbo.JournalEntries
where je.FKSubscriberID == 3 && je.FKAccountID == 3
group je by 1 into jeg
select jeg.Sum(je => je.CreditAmount) - jeg.Sum(je => je.DebitAmount)).First()
```

Without the single group, you can aggregate the difference with

```
(from je in dbo.JournalEntries
where je.FKSubscriberID == 3 && je.FKAccountID == 3
select je.CreditAmount-je.DebitAmount).Sum()
```